# setTimeout in for loop

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Currently I am trying to make a little game maninly for myself for having fun while making it and using it, but i got stuck at a part.

I would like to make a memory game where the program generates a certain array filled with the names of the arrows that should change. So e.g.: left,left,up,down,right with this I would like to change the left arrow 1st only to green than back to normal then since the 2nd time it would happen twice since the 1st 2 elements of the array are "left".

So I have been trying to use setTimeout in JS and tried to look it up how to use it and managed to slowly advance but i kidna got lost in all of the explanations.

My current code changes all the arrows that are listed in the array green then changes them back to normal 1 by 1 (actually I can't see the 1st arrow changin at all but i assume it does just the setTimeout doesnt apply to it since the rest is changing).

```
for (var j = 0; j < narray.length; j++) {

var image = document.getElementById(narray[j]);

 image.src = "arrow-"+narray[j]+"-good.png";
  function(j){
   sesetTimeout(function(){
   var image2 = document.getElementById(narray[j]);
   image2.src = "arrow-"+narray[j]+".png";
}, j*1000);
})(j);
```

I know it is really messy but I have totally got lost in the tutorials I have tried to learn from. So if anyone could help me I would be really greatful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this actually your code as it is in the source? It seems to contain a lot of syntax errors.

Comment: What is your question exactly? (btw you're probably not seeing the first change because the first timeout is 0*1000ms)

Comment: not sure what you want to do, what is inside narray, which images you want to change source and why do you use timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I think will work.

```
k=0;
for (var j = 0; j < narray.length; j++) {

    var image = document.getElementById(narray[j]);

    image.src = "arrow-"+narray[j]+"-good.png";
    setTimeout(function(){
       var image2 = document.getElementById(narray[k]);
       image2.src = "arrow-"+narray[k]+".png";
       k++;
    }, j*1000+500);
}
```

So besides the typos, there's an issue with using "j" from the for loop in the timeout functions because they run later.  So we introduce "k" to keep track of how many of them we've done.  So k will be incremented each time, and here it's a global variable, so as each timeout function actually runs, k will be a different number, and will increment k to be ready for the next one that will be called.

Comment: Thank you very much! Kinda ashamed i couldnt think of such an easy solution, but i could proceed with what i have been planning to do.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

What if you don't use a for loop and you call the function recursive, something like this:

```
function doSomething(j,l){
    if(j>=l) return 'done';
    setTimeout(function(){
       console.log('step: ' + j + ' from: ' + l);

       // add your code here :)

    }, j*1000);
    doSomething(++j,l);
}
doSomething(0,narray.length); // start with 0 and the length of the array
```

Comment: Yes i have tried to do it recursive, though I still failed with the indexes. Besides it works great thanks!